# Is it possible to generate a List to write to Firestore by batch method?

Tags: batch-file, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of numbers which will be user generated.

I have to then write these numbers up to Firestore, with the numbers being the Document ID and I have some fields with data that are also user generated to go along with.

Right now, I am writing the numbers up to Firestore 1 by 1, and it takes 0.5seconds per number, which I feel is taking too long.

Is it possible to structure all these numbers at once and write all these numbers to Firestore in 1 go by batch method?

The number of numbers to write to Firestore is also determined by the user, it could be 10, 15 or 20 numbers.

Even the slightest hint would be really helpful. Thanks to anyone who can help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A batch write is not necessarily any faster than writing documents individually.  Batch writes are **not** intended to be used for performance reasons.  They're intended to implement atomic updates to multiple documents.  If atomic updates of multiple documents is not your goal, then I suggest not spending time thinking about batch writes.